# My Bubblesort can only sort numbers. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

I started this summer with JavaScript. It is my first programming language, and I learn it with the help of a book. Now I coded a bubblesort, and it did not work first. As I wrote it exactly like they did in the book, it still didnt work(my browser (Chrome) just loaded forever). I tried a bit, and after a while i recognized that it just did not work with letters.(In the book they sorted names). So i sorted some numbers. After a while i recognized that it couldnt sort my array neigher when there was no '1'. 
Sorry for bad english, i am not a native speaker. (I translated the variables so it is easier to read).

```
var numbers = [3, 2, 1];
var letters = ["c", "b", "a"];

function bubbleSort(list) {
  do {
    var changed = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
      if (list[i] > [i + 1]) {
        remember = list[i];
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = remember;
        changed = true;
      }
    }
  } while (changed == true);
  return list;
}

alert(bubbleSort(numbers));
alert(bubbleSort(letters));
```

It would be nice if someone tests it in his browser, if this bug also appears there. And if you find any mistakes, please contact me :).
Thanks

Comment: The if condition looks wrong.  `if (list[i] > list[i + i])`

Comment: Is that typo in the real code, or a copying error?

Comment: thank you James :). It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem seems to be this:

```
if (list[i] > [i + 1])
```

Should be:

```
if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
```

That stopped the algorithm from hanging for me and also seems to sort correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try default sort function in js.

```
var numbers = [3, 2, 1];
var letters = ["c", "b", "a"];
alert(numbers.sort());
alert(letters.sort());
```

Comment: First of all, he's trying to learn how to code a sorting algorithm, not how to sort numbers. Second, `numbers.sort()` will not work if there are numbers with different numbers of digits.

Answer (score -3):

Use .charCodeAt(array location) method for each string to sort.

Comment: `.charCodeAt()` can only be used on a string, not an array.